# Emploi de « sédentaire » pour exprimer rester assis

Tags: vocabulaire, usage

Peut-on employer « sédentaire » avec des noms tels que « travail », « profession », « boulot », « poste »?

> J'ai un travail sédentaire. Il m'oblige de rester assis toute la journée.

Quelles tournures peuvent s'employer pour exprimer la même idée ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Travail sédentaire* est tout à fait correct, mais est assez formel and a plutôt un ton administratif ou médical (c'est le genre de terme qu'on retrouvera par exemple dans un rapport de médecin du travail).

Plus familièrement, on peut dire *j'ai un travail de bureau* ou même simplement *je travaille dans un bureau*. Bien que moins précis, cela véhicule typiquement l'idée qu'il s'agit d'un travail où l'on reste la majeure partie de son temps assis derrière un bureau ou un ordinateur.

Answer (score 2):

J'écrirais :

> J'ai un travail **très** sédentaire, il m'oblige **à** rester assis toute la journée.